Can a convex function with a unique support be non-differentiable?
Let $\mathrm{M}$ be an open convex set of a normed space and $f:\mathrm{M} \to \mathbf{R}$ a continuous convex function.
Definition. A support of $f$ at $v \in \mathrm{M}$ is an affine function $x \mapsto f(v) + L(x-v)$ ($L$ is a linear form) such that $f(x) \geq f(v) + L(x-v).$
A well-known result asserts that at every $x \in \mathrm{M}$ the function $f$ will have at least one support at $x$ and that if $f$ is differentiable then it has a unique support. I am interested in the reciprocal proposition.

Suppose that for some $v \in \mathrm{M},$ the function $f$ has a unique support on $v.$ Does this imply that $f$ is differentiable at $v$?

Here is a partial result in $\mathbf{R}^d.$ In this case, it is known that a convex function with partial derivatives will be differentiable. Therefore, suffices to show that if $f$ has a unique support at $v$ then $f$ has partial derivatives. To prove this, consider any unit $u \in \mathbf{R}^d,$ the convex function $t \mapsto f(v + tu)$ (defined on an open interval around the origin) also has a unique support; it is well-known that real-line convex function $\varphi$ defined on an open interval will have sided-derivatives everywhere on that open interval,  in this case, it is easy to see that any $m \in [\varphi_-'(0), \varphi_+'(0)]$ will make the affine function $t \mapsto \varphi(0) + mt$ a support of $\varphi.$ With the aforementiones property of convex function on intervals, if $t \mapsto f(v+tu)$ has a unique support at $t = 0,$ its sided-derivatives must coincide and this imply that $f$ has directional derivatives at $v$ (in every direction). In particular, $f$ has partial derivatives and therefore $f$ is differentiable. Obviously, this case does not extend to infinite dimensions and I do not know a proof or a counterexample.
Addendum: the following theorem can be proved.
Theorem: Suppose that $\mathrm{M}$ is open and convex and $f:\mathrm{M} \to \mathbf{R}$ is convex. In order for the directional derivative $\partial_u f(v) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(v+hu)-f(v)}{h}$ to exist (at a given $v \in \mathrm{M}$) and every unit vector $u$ it is necessary and sufficient that $f$ should have a unique supporting hyperplane at $v.$ When this is the case, $u \mapsto \partial_u f(v)$ is linear.
Sketch of proof. After two translations, $f(0) = 0.$ Suppose now $f$ has unique support at the origin. Then, there exist one and only one linear form $L$ such that $f(x) \geq L(x)$. For any unit $u,$ we have $f(tu) \geq t L(u)$ for all $t$ small enough. Thus, the convex function $t \mapsto f(tu)$ dominates the linear form $t L(u)$; by Banach's extension theorem, the linear form $tL(u) = L(tu)$ (defined on $\mathbf{R} u$) extends to a linear form (on $\mathrm{V}$) such that $\bar L(x) \leq f(x),$ that is to say, the extension $\bar{L}$ is a supporting hyperplane of $f$ at the origin and it therefore coincides with $L.$ Thus, $t \mapsto f(tu)$ cannot have more than one supporting line at the origin and this implies that this function is differentiable, i.e., $f$ has directional derivative at the origin with direction $u.$
Reciprocally, suppose $f$ has directional derivative. Convexity of $f$ shows it must have at least one supporting hyperplane at the origin, i.e., there is a linear form $L$ such that $f(x) \geq L(x).$ For unit $u$ and all small $t,$ $f(tu) \geq L(tu) = t L(u).$ Dividing by $t$ and considering cases $t > 0$ and $t < 0,$ we see that $\partial_u f(0) = \lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{f(tu)}{t} = L(u)$ and therefore $L$ is uniquely determined and $\partial_u f(0)$ is linear in $u$. QED
Therefore, the original question becomes:

Suppose $\mathrm{M}$ is an open convex set of a normed space and $f:\mathrm{M} \to \mathbf{R}$ convex and continuous. Assume $f$ possesses directional derivatives everywhere on $\mathrm{M}$ (and on every direction) and that $u \mapsto \partial_u f(v)$ defines a linear function for every $v \in \mathrm{M}$. Is $f$ (Frechet) differentiable?


Do you mean to assume that $f$ is convex?

Yes, I assumed "$f:\mathrm{M} \to \mathbf{R}$ a convex function."

You also said "the reciprocal" so it wasn't entirely clear what you were and weren't reciprocating. (The statement is not true for nonconvex functions and the Dirichlet function $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is a counterexample.)

$f(x) = \vert x \vert +1$ has unique support at $f(0)$ but is not differentiable there.

@CyclotomicField maybe I should add the definition of support? That function has infinitely many supports at zero. Any function $t \mapsto 1+mt$ for $m \in [-1,1]$ is a support.

I believe this follows immediately from the definition of the total derivative as the unique supporting hyperplane is the $df_a$ so that  $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{|f(x)-f(a)-df_a(x-a)|}{|x-a|}=0$.

@CyclotomicField the definition of supporting hyperplane that $f(x) \geq f(a) + L(x-a)$ and we want to conclude that $f(x) = f(a) + L(x-a) + o(x-a)$ using that (1) $f$ is convex and (2) there is no other $L$ satisfying the hypothesis. How is it immediate?

Let $X$ be Banach, $f:X \to \mathbb R$ convex. Define
$$
\partial f(x) := \{g\in X^*: \ g(y-x) \le f(y) - f(x) \quad \forall y\in X\}.
$$
Here, $X^*$ is the (topological) dual of $X$.
Then we have the following theorem, for a proof see Proposition 2.40 in [Barbu, Precupanu: Convexity
and Optimization in Banach Spaces].

If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, and $\partial f(x_0)$ is a singleton,
then $f$ is Gateaux differentiable at $x_0$.

The statement is also true if $X$ is a locally convex topological vector space, see Proposition I.5.3 in [Ekeland, Temam: Convex Analysis and Variational Problems]. For a discussion of continuity of convex functions, see Section I.2.3 in this book.

The statement above is not true without continuity: Let $\phi:X\to \mathbb R$ be linear and discontinuous. Then define $f(x) = |\phi(x)|$.
Since $f$ has global minimum at $x=0$, we have $\{0\} \in \partial f(0)$.
One can check that any linear $g:X \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$ g(y) \le f(y)\quad \forall y\in X$$
has to satisfy $g = \lambda \phi$ with $\lambda\in [-1,+1]$.
The only continuous functional of this form is zero, so $\partial f(0)=\{0\}$.

Also Frechet differentiability is not implied. To see this, take $X = L^1(0,1)$,
$$
f(x) := \int_0^1 \sqrt{x(t)^2+1} \ dt,
$$
which is convex and continuous (by dominated convergence).
Set $x=0$. Then $f$ is Gateaux differentiable with $f'(x)=0$.: Take $h \in X$ and $t\ge 0$, then
$$
\frac1s\left|f(x+sh) -f(x)\right| 
= \frac1s\left| \int_0^1 \sqrt{s^2h(t)^2+1} -1 \ dt\right|
= \left|\int_0^1 \frac{s |h(t)|^2}{\sqrt{s^2h(t)^2+1} + 1} \right|.
$$
This converges to zero by dominated convergence, as
the integrand is dominated by the integrable function $|h|$.
Let $h = \chi_{ (0,\epsilon) }$.
Then
$$
f(x+h)-f(x) - f'(x)h = [\epsilon \sqrt 2 + (1-\epsilon)]- 1 - 0 
= (\sqrt 2-1)\epsilon = (\sqrt 2-1)\|h\|_{L^1}.
$$
so $f$ is not Frechet.

Thanks, no, continuity of $f$ nor $L$ is required. But now that I think about it, it seems obvious we should ask for it. In other words, we should start with a continuous convex function $f$ (this forces every support to be continuous), and ask if uniqueness of support will imply differentiability of $f.$

Can you please elaborate in your last claim? A convex lower-semicontinuous is continuous (I think it suffices lower semicontinuity at a point to conclude continuity everywhere on the open convex set $M$), that is true. Then $f(x) \geq f(v) + L(x-v)$ will force $L$ to be bounded around $v$ and therefore continuous since it is linear (so we need not require $L$ to be linear; continuous convex functions cannot have unbounded supports).

The claim is true for convex functions that are continuous at $x$, this can be found in text books. I am away from my books, so no reference for now.

I'll wait for you reference then. I have only a few books in convex analysis and none proves the general case (only the finite dimensional case as I did in the main post box).

As I proved above, $f$ has unique support at a point iff it is Gateaux differentiable there. So your second example the conclusion should be amended to "$f$ is not differentiable."

I completely rewrote the answer. Please have a look.

The definitions that book uses are different from other books, basically they use topological duals as opposed to algebraic duals. That is why I proved a function has directional derivatives at a point iff it has a unique supporting hyperplane (I have no problem with this small change). In your example against (Frechet) differentiability, it seems you are using $x = 0$ and proposing $f'(0) = 0.$ However, $f(0)=1$ and $f(h) = \int_0^1 \sqrt{\chi_{(0,\varepsilon)}+1} \geq 1.$ The same radical trick you did shows in fact that $f(h)-1=\int_0^1 \frac{h^2}{\sqrt{h^2+1}+1} \leq |h^2|_1.$

Corrected that computation. Note that $|h^2 |{L^1} = |h|{L^2}^2$, which is $+\infty$ if $h \in L^1 \setminus L^2$. (This reasoning shows that $f$ is Frechet on $L^2$, but it is not Frechet on $L^1$).

Thank you @daw, this was an excellent example. One can in fact use the $L^i$ norm but on $\mathrm{V} = \mathscr{C}_\mathbf{R}[0,1]$ and then take $h=1$ on $[0, \varepsilon],$ $h = 0$ on $[2\varepsilon, 1]$ and affine between $\varepsilon$ and $2\varepsilon$, just so that this example actually fits in any third semester calculus curriculum of any (worthwhile) maths program.
